# How can I get my sharedpreferences to work correctly?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm having trouble getting my sharedpreferences to work. I'm trying to load in data from a textbox in another activity into a textview. I don't get any errors, but it keeps returning the default value of "nameKey".

Here is where the data is being entered and saved

```
public class ActivitySettings extends AppCompatActivity {

 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
final String Name = "nameKey";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final EditText enterName1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName1); 
    final EditText enterName2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterName2); 

    Button btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String n = enterName1.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Name, n);
    editor.commit();

        }
    });
```

and here's a different activity where i'm trying to read in the data and set it to a textview

```
public class ActivityDuel extends AppCompatActivity {

public String getPrefs(String n, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return preferences.getString(n, "nameKey");
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_duel);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final TextView txtD1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtD1);
    txtD1.setText(getPrefs("name", this));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call like this

```
 txtD1.setText(getPrefs("nameKey", this));
```

And your `getPrefs()` function should like below

```
public String getPrefs(String n, Context context) {
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  return preferences.getString(n, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to create a class for handle your `SharedPreferences` and add your key as static string to it and use methods for insert and read. here an example:

***SettingProvider.class***

```java
public class SettingProvider {

    private static final String SETTING_PROVIDER_NAME = "setting";
    public static final String NAME = "name"
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private static SettingProvider ourInstance;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private SettingProvider(Context context) {
        if (context == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("context must be valid!");
        this.sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTING_PROVIDER_NAME, 0);
    }

    public static SettingProvider getInstance(Context context) {
        if (ourInstance == null) {
            ourInstance = new SettingProvider(context);
        }
        return ourInstance;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        return this.sharedPreferences.edit().setString(NAME, name).apply();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.sharedPreferences.getString(NAME, "");
    }
}
```

now for use in activity

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_duel);
    SettingProvider.getInstance(this).setName("the name");
    String name = SettingProvider.getInstance(this).getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are saving a shared preferences key of 'Name', so from the field `final String Name = "nameKey";` the preferences key is 'nameKey'

Then when you try and get the string out you are using "name" as the lookup key value and as it doesn't exist it gets set to the default of 'nameKey' so I think you need to change this `txtD1.setText(getPrefs("name", this));` to `txtD1.setText(getPrefs(Name, this));`